# How to append a variable from another function python3

Tags: python-3.x, append

I want to append the date2 from this function into

```
def date_register():
     print("Enter date of registration")
     year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
     month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
     day = int(input("Enter a day: "))
     date1 = datetime.date(year,month,day)
     date2 = date1 + timedelta(days = 140)
     print("Check out date:",date2)
```

this function and it came out date2 is not defined

```
def update_A(row):  #to update the roomA
    if len(roomA[row]) < 2: #if roomA is less than 2
        name = input("Enter your name here: ")
        print(date_register())
        roomA[row].append((name,date2))
        print("Your room no. is {} at row {}".format(roomA[row].index((name,date2))+1,row))
        print(Continue())
```

Seeking for help thank you

Comment: My friend, you forgot to `return` the result of function `date_register` to make it available in `update_a`.

Comment: Could u provide the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected one or two other minor mistakes.

```
import datetime

def date_register():
    print("Enter date of registration")
    year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
    day = int(input("Enter a day: "))
    date1 = datetime.date(year,month,day)
    date2 = date1 + datetime.timedelta(days = 140)
    print("Check out date:",date2)
    return date2

def update_A(row):  #to update the roomA
    if len(roomA[row]) < 2: #if roomA is less than 2
        name = input("Enter your name here: ")
        checkout_date = date_register()
        print(checkout_date)
        roomA[row].append((name,checkout_date))
        print("Your room no. is {} at row {}".format(roomA[row].index((name,checkout_date))+1,row))

roomA = {1: []}
update_A(1)
```

Here's the output.

```
Enter your name here: John
Enter date of registration
Enter a year: 1954
Enter a month: 7
Enter a day: 12
Check out date: 1954-11-29
1954-11-29
Your room no. is 1 at row 1
```

Apparently you need to work out how to print the check-out date.

Answer (score 2):

`date2` is not defined because it is not within the scope of `update_A`
Please read [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) for more information on scope.

You also seem to be confusing `return` and `print`

In `update_A`, you write `print(date_register())` but `date_register` doesn't return anything to be printed.

`print` sends string representations to the console and can't be used for assignment. Instead use `return` which basically forces a function call to resolve to the value next to the `return` statement.
For example:

```
def foo:
    return "bar"
print(foo())
```

when `foo` is called, it will resolve to `"bar"` which is then printed to the console. for more on the difference and usage of `print()` and `return` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python)

To use `date2` in `update_A` you should return it and assign it as follows:

```
def date_register():
     print("Enter date of registration")
     year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
     month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
     day = int(input("Enter a day: "))
     date1 = datetime.date(year,month,day)
     date2 = date1 + timedelta(days = 140)
     print("Check out date:",date2)
     return date2 
def update_A(row):  #to update the roomA
    if len(roomA[row]) < 2: #if roomA is less than 2
        name = input("Enter your name here: ")
        date2 = date_register() #assign date2 returned value
        print(date2)
        roomA[row].append((name,date2))
        print("Your room no. is {} at row {}".format(roomA[row].index((name,date2))+1,row))
        print(Continue())
```